# huge log.samba-bgqd

Tags: samba

Since updating to 22.04, samba has started to produce an additional log file named log.samba-bgqd, into which appr. every 12 minutes a block of 1,000 lines with errors is logged. The error messages look like this:

```
[2022/10/08 11:46:08,  1] ../../source3/printing/print_standard.c:147(std_pcap_cache_reload)
  std_pcap_cache_reload: WARNING: You have some printer names that are longer than 15 characters. These may not be accessible to some older clients!
[2022/10/08 11:46:08,  3] ../../source3/printing/pcap.c:194(pcap_cache_reload)
  reload status: ok
[2022/10/08 11:46:08,  3] ../../source3/lib/util_procid.c:53(pid_to_procid)
  pid_to_procid: messaging_dgm_get_unique failed: No such file or directory
[2022/10/08 11:46:08,  3] ../../source3/lib/messages.c:918(send_all_fn)
  send_all_fn: messaging_send_buf to 1043 failed: NT_STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND
[2022/10/08 11:46:08,  3] ../../source3/lib/util_procid.c:53(pid_to_procid)
  pid_to_procid: messaging_dgm_get_unique failed: No such file or directory
[2022/10/08 11:46:08,  3] ../../source3/lib/messages.c:918(send_all_fn)
  send_all_fn: messaging_send_buf to 1179 failed: NT_STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND
[2022/10/08 11:46:08,  3] ../../source3/lib/util_procid.c:53(pid_to_procid)
  pid_to_procid: messaging_dgm_get_unique failed: No such file or directory
[2022/10/08 11:46:08,  3] ../../source3/lib/messages.c:918(send_all_fn)
  send_all_fn: messaging_send_buf to 18889 failed: NT_STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND
[2022/10/08 11:46:08,  3] ../../source3/lib/util_procid.c:53(pid_to_procid)
  pid_to_procid: messaging_dgm_get_unique failed: No such file or directory
[2022/10/08 11:46:08,  3] ../../source3/lib/messages.c:918(send_all_fn)
  send_all_fn: messaging_send_buf to 873 failed: NT_STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND
[2022/10/08 11:46:08,  3] ../../source3/lib/util_procid.c:53(pid_to_procid)
  pid_to_procid: messaging_dgm_get_unique failed: No such file or directory
[2022/10/08 11:46:08,  3] ../../source3/lib/messages.c:918(send_all_fn)
  send_all_fn: messaging_send_buf to 1012 failed: NT_STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND
[2022/10/08 11:46:08,  3] ../../source3/lib/util_procid.c:53(pid_to_procid)
  pid_to_procid: messaging_dgm_get_unique failed: No such file or directory
[2022/10/08 11:46:08,  3] ../../source3/lib/messages.c:918(send_all_fn)
  send_all_fn: messaging_send_buf to 1294 failed: NT_STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND
[2022/10/08 11:46:08,  3] ../../source3/lib/util_procid.c:53(pid_to_procid)
  pid_to_procid: messaging_dgm_get_unique failed: No such file or directory
[2022/10/08 11:46:08,  3] ../../source3/lib/messages.c:918(send_all_fn)
  send_all_fn: messaging_send_buf to 846 failed: NT_STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND
[2022/10/08 11:46:08,  3] ../../source3/lib/util_procid.c:53(pid_to_procid)
  pid_to_procid: messaging_dgm_get_unique failed: No such file or directory
[2022/10/08 11:46:08,  3] ../../source3/lib/messages.c:918(send_all_fn)
  send_all_fn: messaging_send_buf to 876 failed: NT_STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND
[2022/10/08 11:46:08,  3] ../../source3/lib/util_procid.c:53(pid_to_procid)
  pid_to_procid: messaging_dgm_get_unique failed: No such file or directory
[2022/10/08 11:46:08,  3] ../../source3/lib/messages.c:918(send_all_fn)
  send_all_fn: messaging_send_buf to 1340 failed: NT_STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND
[2022/10/08 11:46:08,  3] ../../source3/lib/util_procid.c:53(pid_to_procid)
  pid_to_procid: messaging_dgm_get_unique failed: No such file or directory
[2022/10/08 11:46:08,  3] ../../source3/lib/messages.c:918(send_all_fn)
  send_all_fn: messaging_send_buf to 1529 failed: NT_STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND
[2022/10/08 11:46:08,  3] ../../source3/lib/util_procid.c:53(pid_to_procid)
  pid_to_procid: messaging_dgm_get_unique failed: No such file or directory
[2022/10/08 11:46:08,  3] ../../source3/lib/messages.c:918(send_all_fn)
  send_all_fn: messaging_send_buf to 902 failed: NT_STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND
[2022/10/08 11:46:08,  3] ../../source3/lib/util_procid.c:53(pid_to_procid)
  pid_to_procid: messaging_dgm_get_unique failed: No such file or directory
[2022/10/08 11:46:08,  3] ../../source3/lib/messages.c:918(send_all_fn)
  send_all_fn: messaging_send_buf to 852 failed: NT_STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND
[2022/10/08 11:46:08,  3] ../../source3/lib/util_procid.c:53(pid_to_procid)
  pid_to_procid: messaging_dgm_get_unique failed: No such file or directory
[2022/10/08 11:46:08,  3] ../../source3/lib/messages.c:918(send_all_fn)
  send_all_fn: messaging_send_buf to 16917 failed: NT_STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND
```

Any idea for what the error is and how I could fix this? I'm not noticing/getting complaints about any issues on the client side.

Also, it would be great if this logfile wouldn't just keep growing, as it is flooding my boot disk.

Samba conf:

```
workgroup = MYGROUP
server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
wins support = yes
dns proxy = no
guest account = nobody
os level = 33
local master = yes
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
log level = 3 auth:10
max log size = 1000
syslog = 0
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
security = user
obey pam restrictions = no
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
passwd chat = *Enter\snew\sUNIX\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\sUNIX\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
printing = bsd
socket options = TCP_NODELAY

[netstore]
   comment = data
   path = /srv/netstore
   guest ok = yes
   available = yes
   force create mode = 0777
   force directory mode = 0777
   hosts allow = 192.168.1.0/24 192.168.2.0/24 10.8.0.0/24
   browsable = yes
   public = no
   writable = yes

[Webpages]
   comment = websites
   path = /var/www
   guest ok = no
   available = yes
   force create mode = 0777
   force directory mode = 0777
   browsable = yes
   public = no
   writable = yes
```

Thanks!

Comment: You seem to have only the one error repeated over and over. failed: NT_STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND From what I see on many web sites after searching this message it is most likely caused by some recent update.

Comment: Interesting, you appear to want use guest access, by having 'guest ok = yes' set in the shares, but you have immediately turned this off by having 'public = no' set in the shares, last one wins. Are you also aware that 'public' is a synonym for 'guest ok' ? or to put it another way, the mean the same.
Not that it matters, guest access isn't going to work because you do not have 'map to guest = bad user' set in the 'global' part of your smb.conf

Comment: I have the same problem. Ubuntu 22.04.1, samba 4.15.9

Comment: I haven't been able to solve this, yet. David above suggested that it might be an issue with one of the Samba updates. I guess this means that all we can do is hope for another update to fix this.